# If foreign key does not exist create it. Django framework

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, orm

Imagine you have a table A which has a foreign key pointing to other table B, but in that B table there is no such key.

What should you do if you want to achieve this functionality - add the key in the table B if the key does not exist?

Are there any serious concerns about performance issues?

Is firstly inserting the record to B then to A worth thinking about?

Comment: "Imagine you have a table A which has a foreign key pointing to other table B, but in that B table there is no such key."  I'm having trouble imagining I did such a poor job designing tables A and B that such a row could exist in A.

Comment: I could see how this can happen. If you're creating A and it depends on the creation of B then yes make them at the same time. But otherwise it seems like maybe you're doing something wrong.

Comment: And how about I firstly add the record to B if the record does not exist and then add the wanted record to A? But would this result in noticible performance loss? Or maybe the more important question - is it 'the right' way to go?

Comment: For example if you were making a system to manage scheduling classes and you had an interface to create a class then perhaps I could see something where you create the class and a new professor at the same time and the class is foreign keyed on the professor. It's a bit sloppy and you might get yourself into trouble accidentally but it shouldn't have serious performance issues.

Comment: I am facing this same scenario where I have to do as asked in the question here but I am not comfortable in doing this as I know its kind of sloppy. Is there any alternate design suggestion for this?